# Issue Accessing File Storage in Azure WorkerRole using Startup Script

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure Cloud Service Worker Role which needs a separate Windows Service installed to redirect application tracing to a centralized server.  I've placed the installation binaries for this Windows Service in a Storage Account's file storage as shown below. I then have my startup task call a batch file, which in turn executes a power-shell script to retrieve the file and install the service

When Azure deploys a new instance of the role, the script execution fails with the following error:

> Cannot find path 
>   '\\{name}.file.core.windows.net\utilities\slab1-1.zip' because it does 
>   not exist

However, when I run the script after connecting through RDP, all is fine.  Does anybody know why this might be happening?  Here is the script below...

```
cmdkey /add:$storageAccountName.file.core.windows.net /user:$shareUser /pass:$shareAccessKey

net use * \\$storageAccountName.file.core.windows.net\utilities

mkdir slab
copy \\$storageAccountName.file.core.windows.net\utilities\$package .\slab\$package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always have problem here and there by using a script to access the mounted azure file drive. I believe this is more or less related to the drive is mounted only for the current user and may not always work the same when called from a script.

I ended up pulling files from azure file the hard way without network drive.

```
$source= $stroageAccountName
$sourceKey = $shareAccessKey
$sharename = "utilities"
$package = "slab1-1.zip"
$dest = ".\slab\" + $package

#Define Azure file share root
$ctx=New-AzureStorageContext $source $sourceKey
$share = get-AzureStorageShare $sharename -Context $ctx
Get-AzureStorageFileContent -share $share -Destination $dest -Path $package -confirm:$false
```

Code example here will get you a good start:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/

It would be harder to manage if you have more complex folder structure, but objects there are [CloudFileDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfiledirectory.aspx) and [CloudFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfile.aspx), property and methods there works seamlessly for me in powershell 4.0

*[Azure Powershell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/) module is required for 'Get-AzureStorageFileContent' cmdlet

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the relevant example with all the correct parameters too!