# Trying to inject powershell commands in to Azure RM VMs via JSON template Custom Extension

Tags: json, powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Both of these lines of code work perfect in downloading, unzipping and executing all my .bat and .msi files locally on my Azure RM VMs, I've been deploying through an ARM-Template that I've modified like crazy and it's probably full of holes since I'm very new to all this.

I've been trying to shoot them up through a JSON Custom Script Extension through an Azure File Share to no availe, also been trying to get them up through blob containers with the same results. I keep getting the Verbose error message that "The network path can not be found." and I've been scanning the logs and can't find any info on how to get around this. Am I approaching what I am trying to achieve in the right way? Is there a better way to get my installs up automatically on deploy with dynamic parameters?

```
cmdkey /add:$ArtifactsStorageAccountName.file.core.windows.net /u:$ArtifactsStorageAccountName /pass:$StorageAccountKey
Copy-Item -Path $InstallCustomScriptExtensionScriptFilePath -Destination C:\
Copy-Item -Path $InstallCustomScriptExtensionZIPFilePath -Destination C:\
Unblock-File -Path C:\UnzipMetaforceInstall.ps1
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\UnzipMetaforceInstall.ps1
PowerShell net use Z: \\$ArtifactsStorageAccountName.file.core.windows.net\$FileShareName\InstallMetaforce /u:artifactsstoaccastst $StorageAccountKey
PowerShell Copy-Item -Path Z:\UnzipMetaforceInstall.ps1 -Destination C:\
PowerShell Copy-Item -Path Z:\InstallMetaforce.zip -Destination C:\
PowerShell Unblock-File -Path C:\UnzipMetaforceInstall.ps1
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\UnzipMetaforceInstall.ps1

    {
      "name": "InstallCustomScriptExtension",
      "type": "extensions",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmNamePrefix'), copyindex(1)))]",
        "DSCConfig"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "InstallCustomScriptExtension"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": [
            "[parameters('InstallCustomScriptExtensionScriptFilePath')]"
          ],
          "commandToExecute": "[parameters('CommandToExecuteCustomScript')]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "storageAccountName": "[parameters('ArtifactsStorageAccountName')]",
          "storageAccountKey": "[parameters('StorageAccountKey')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

Looking forward to whatever help I can get, I've been stuck at this step for about two weeks now. If you want any additional info or if I'm unclear in any way please tell me and I'll see what I can do. First time posting, long time reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to crack it earlier this weekend. Made my scripts dynamic through powershell / JSON parameters as well and it works like a charm.

```
        {
      "name": "InstallCustomScriptExtension",
      "type": "extensions",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(parameters('vmNamePrefix'), copyindex(1)))]",
        "DSCConfig"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "InstallCustomScriptExtension"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": [
            "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', parameters('InstallCustomScriptExtensionScriptFilePath'))]"
          ],
          "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ', parameters('InstallCustomScriptExtensionScriptFilePath'), ' -ArtifactsStorageAccountName ', parameters('ArtifactsStorageAccountName'), ' -FileShareName ', parameters('FileShareName'), ' -StorageAccountKey ', parameters('StorageAccountKey'))]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "storageAccountName": "[parameters('ArtifactsStorageAccountName')]",
          "storageAccountKey": "[parameters('StorageAccountKey')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

The inside of my Unzip script now looks like this:

```
param(
[string]$ArtifactsStorageAccountName,
[string]$FileShareName,
[string]$StorageAccountKey
)

PowerShell net use Z: \\$ArtifactsStorageAccountName.file.core.windows.net\$FileShareName\Install /u:$ArtifactsStorageAccountName $StorageAccountKey; PowerShell Copy-Item -Path Z:\Install.zip -Destination C:\;
$shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace("C:\Install.zip")
MkDir("C:\Install")
foreach ($item in $zip.items()) {
$shell.Namespace("C:\Install").CopyHere($item)
}

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

cd "C:\Install"
Unblock-File -Path "C:\Install\Install.ps1"
"C:\Install\Install.ps1" | Invoke-Expression
```

It probably needs some more work and the Protected Settings in my JSON template probably is unnecessary but at the moment it does the job and I now have a one-click deploy that I can keep building on.

Answer (score 0):

"The network path can not be found." lead me to believe this is kind of the [similar situation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646885/issue-accessing-file-storage-in-azure-workerrole-using-startup-script/36653278#36653278) where I think attach azure file as a network drive with script is not always reliable. I have given a solution to directly download from Azure file in the linked topic I think would help you as well. Let me know if it doesn't work out for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kai Zhao, will give it a look asap! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at the sample here:

https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples

And then look at the folder:

https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/tree/master/VMCSEInstallFilePS

The sample template in the folder uses a custom script extension to install a file from Azure blob storage (or another url).

The root of the repo contains a PowerShell script that does 2 things:

1. copies the file to install from the local machine (e.g. build machine) into Azure storage and secures it with a sasToken and
2. Deploys the AzureRM Template and passes the URI and sasToken for the blob into the deployment.

Also note the "forceUpdateTag" in the sample (see: [Issues deploying dscExtension to Azure VMSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845024/issues-deploying-dscextension-to-azure-vmss/36891867#36891867)).  If you need to deploy the json template over and over again, this is needed to get the extension to run when the VM already exists (you can also Remove-AzureRMVMExtension via PowerShell, the tag may be quicker).

Answer (score 0):

If your script doesn't include any secrets or intellectual property, you can upload it to a blob storage container and set the access policy to '**blob**' (not '**private**')  and then you don't have to worry with SAS Tokens.

This template worked for me (today April 28, 2016) with blob storage and powershell.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/CustomScriptExtension')]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "CustomScriptExtension"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
    "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": [ "[parameters('launchScriptBlobUri')]" ],
      "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file ',parameters('scriptFileName'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe Microsoft can explain why my other extensions have type='extensions' but this one has type='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions'  but it works today.

Comment: I think they changed it a few months ago, it sure looks like it when you scroll through billions of guides. :)