# Issues deploying dscExtension to Azure VMSS

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I've been having some issues deploying a dscExtension to an Azure virtual machine scale set (VMSS) using a deployment template.

Here's how I've added it to my template:

```
{
  "name": "dscExtension",
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
    "type": "DSC",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.9",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
      "ModulesUrl": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', 'MyDscPackage.zip', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
      "ConfigurationFunction": "CmvmProcessor.ps1\\CmvmProcessor",
      "Properties": [
        {
          "Name": "ServiceCredentials",
          "Value": {
            "UserName": "parameters('administratorLogin')",
            "Password": "parameters('administratorLoginPassword')"
          },
          "TypeName": "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The VMSS itself is successfully deploying, but when I browse the InstanceView of the individual VMs, the dscExtension shows the failed status with an error message.

The problems I'm having are as follows:

The ARM deployment does not try to update the dscExtension upon redeploy.  I am used to MSDeploy web app extensions where the artifacts are updated and the code is redeployed on each new deployment.  I do not know how to force it to update the dscExtension with new binaries.  In fact it only seems to give an error on the first deploy of the VMSS, then it won't even try again.

The error I'm getting is for old code that doesn't exist anymore.

I had a bug previously in a custom DSC Powershell script where I tried to use the *-replace* operator which is supposed to create a *$Matches* variable but it was saying *$Matches* didn't exist.

In any case, I've since refactored the code and deleted the entire resource group then redeployed.  The dscExtension is still giving the same error.  I've verified the blob storage account where my DSC .zip is located no longer has the code which is capable of producing this error message.  Azure must be caching the dscExtension somewhere.  I can't get it to use my new blob .zip that I upload before each deployment.

Any insight into the DSC Extension and how to force it to update on deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may be running into multiple things here, so trying the simple one first.  In order to get a VM extension to run on a subsequent deployment you have to "seed" it. (and you're right this is different than the rest of AzureRM)  Take a look at this template:

https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/blob/master/VMDSCInstallFile/azuredeploy.json

There is a property on the DSC extension called:

```
              "forceUpdateTag" : "changeThisToEnsureScriptRuns-maxlength=50",
```

The property value must be different if you ever want the extension to run again.  So for example, if you wanted it to run every time you'd seed it with a random number or a guid.  You could also use version numbers if you wanted to version it somehow.  The point is, if the value in the template is the same as the one you're passing in, the extension won't run again.

That sample uses a VM, but the VMSS syntax *should* be the same.  That property also applies to other extensions (e.g. custom script).

The part that seems odd is that you said you deleted the entire RG and couldn't get it to accept the new package...  That sounds bad (i.e. like a bug).  If the above doesn't fix it, we may need to dig deeper into the template and script.  LMK...

Comment: Thank you.  I was actually able to get the DSC extension working properly by changing to TypeHandlerVersion 2.17 and using the JSON syntax that I could only find here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/02/26/arm-dsc-extension-settings/

Comment: But I still need to force it to update of course, so this answer is great.

Comment: another debugging tip is that if you do have problems getting it to re-run you can remove the extension and leave the rest of the VM and RG intact - much faster for debugging.  I use PowerShell's "Remove-AzureRmVMExtension".

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that was updated to also work with scalesets.  Very useful!

Comment: This answer works for a single VM, but I can't get DSC update working on a VM ScaleSet which I'm deploying as a JSON template.

Comment: Looking at the VM DscExtension log files, it doesn't even have a log entry for when I deploy to the VMSS after the first time.  So it seems the nested "extensionProfile" object is not updated.

Comment: Trevor - just so I'm clear - what you're seeing is that on the VMSS, you don't see the DSC extension executed again when using the forceUpdateTag?

Comment: Turns out I had the VMSS upgradePolicy set to mode: Manual.  I must have thought this had something to do with Windows updates... but that's why my extension wasn't updating with each deploy in the case of VMSS.  Working now!

Comment: UpgadePolicy set to Manual is the example value used in most VMSS configurations I've seen. Really, all examples should be using Automatic.